# Use auto_ptr in VC6 dll cause crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
// dll
#include <memory>

__declspec(dllexport) std::auto_ptr<int> get();

__declspec(dllexport) std::auto_ptr<int> get()
{
    return std::auto_ptr<int>(new int());
}
```

---

```
// exe
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

__declspec(dllimport) std::auto_ptr<int> get();

int main() {
    {
        std::auto_ptr<int> x = get();
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
    getchar();
}
```

---

The following code run perfectly OK under VC9. However, under VC6, I will experience an immediate crash with the following message.

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program:
>   C:\Projects\use_dynamic_link\Debug\use_dynamic_link.exe
>   File: dbgheap.c Line: 1044
>
> Expression:
>   _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Is it exporting auto_ptr under VC6 is not allowed?

It is a known problem that exporting STL collection classes through DLL.

[Access Violation When Accessing an STL Object Through A Pointer or Reference In A Different DLL or EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451714/access-violation-when-accessing-an-stl-object-through-a-pointer-or-reference-in-a)

However, I Google around and do not see anything mention for std::auto_ptr.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DLL has its own heap, so you have to make sure you new and delete from the same context.

Comment: Why the problem doesn't occur in VC9?

Comment: OK. I do find out why the problem doesn't occur in VC9. In VC9, I am dynamically link to run time library. In VC6, I am using static link. See my additional posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that the exe and dll projects in VC9 are set up for the CRT to be targeted as a shared dll, while one or both of the VC6 projects is targeting the static CRT (non-dll).

Alternatively, both the dll and exe are targeting different versions of a shared CRT dll (so they actually use 2 different CRTs).

In VC6, check the run-time library option in the Code Generation category of the C/C++ Project properties.  Make sure both the exe and dll target the same DLL library option.

Answer (score 1):

You're violating the ODR (one definition rule) and most likely the member functions are inlined -- since they are inlined with two different definitions of `std::auto_ptr` you get undefined behavior.

On top of that, as Eddy points out, when `auto_ptr::~auto_ptr` frees the held object, it will call `operator delete` in the EXE instead of in the DLL where `operator new` was called.  This mismatch can also produce a crash.

In general it is very fragile to export implemented classes (interface classes consisting solely of pure virtual functions, and exporting a free factory function for construction) are OK and then you don't use `__declspec(dllexport)` on the class, only on the factory function.

Comment: Looks like an egg and chicken problem. My natural reflex would be, because of exception safety, to put an auto_ptr around the pointer that the dll function returned. But then I can run into the delete by different runtimes problem.

Comment: @user: Try `com_ptr_t`, and implement a `Release` function in the object itself.  COM/DCOM/ActiveX uses this method to great effect for sharing components between modules/compilers/languages/runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I realize the root cause. It is caused by

**DLL Memory Manager Mixup**

[DLL memory manager mixup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085873/dll-memory-manager-mixup)

1. allocate a memory from a DLL
2. return the pointer to EXE
3. try to delete pointer from EXE

Step (3) will only work fine, if we link to run-time library dynamically (under options C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Use run-time library)

If we link to run-time library statically, the memory manager used by DLL, might be different from the memory manager used by EXE.

Comment: You mean the run time library options in the project settings were mixed up?